# Cant add more content?

Tags: html, css

I have added a header and I have also added one paragraph, but each time I try adding content it does not show. I have tried a list, a paragraph and a header and neither of them have worked. I have no clue why!

HTML

```
<div id="midwrap"><a class="headerone">Tag Helper</a>
<p class="paragraph1tag">Select the coding in which you are using for the "Tag Helper".</p>
<p class="paragraph1tag">Selesdgsdgdsgct the coding in which you are using for the "Tag Helper".</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#midwrap {
    width: 70%;
    height: 90%;
    border-left: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right; 
    clear: right;
    margin-right: 7%;
}

.headerone {
    color: #000000;;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.paragraph1 {
    color: #000000;;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` in your rules for `#midwrap`